# PETSc SNES for user defined state

Tags: nonlinear-equations, iterative-method, petsc

How to use PETSc SNES ([scalable nonlinear equation solver](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/SNES/index.html)), when the solution is not a vector but a user defined state?

I am implementing a non-linear mechanics problem (geometrically exact shell 5-paramter model), the update

$$X^{(k+1)} = X^{(k)} + \Delta_X$$

is not additive and requires the use of exponential maps.

More specifically, the state I mentioned above stores $ X $ :
$$ X = \left \{ \Phi , \Lambda  \right \} $$ 
$ \Phi $ (vector of size 3) is mid-surface coordinates and have direct updates i.e  $$ \Phi _{n+1} = \Phi_{n} + \Delta \Phi $$
While $ \Lambda $, the rotation matrix (correpondiong to director at mid surface), is updated through exponential map (the update increment is a vector of size 2, which is obtained after exploiting the one to one connection between tangent space of SO3 and S2 and fixing a reference vector).
The residual at  each point of mid surface(node) is a vector of size 5 and consists of $ \Lambda $ , $ \Phi $ and their derivatives.

I am using Newton-Raphson and many times the solution couldn't converge using a complete step size. Consequently, I thought of resorting to PETSc SNES (line search).

At any state, I know the residual vector and stiffness matrix. 
I could not figure how to make sense of solution vector that I get from SNES solver (or to send data to SNES), given that I have my own update procedure.

Comment: Could you write out the question in proper mathematical notation please? In particular, it's not clear to me what $X$ is, what equation is being solved by SNES and how it relates to $X$ and $\Delta_X$, what exactly is being updated and where, what the unknowns are, etc.

Comment: you should ask this q to the [petsc-users mailing list](https://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/petsc-users/).